# How can I create a Notification.Action and add it to a custom notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-support-library, wear-os

I'm following Google's instructions here https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html

However, unsurprisingly, their code doesn't work. Specifically I'm trying to do this:

```
// Build the notification and add the action via WearableExtender
        Notification notification =
                new Notification.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.buzz_icon)
                        .setContentTitle("Buzz")
                        .setContentText("OpenBuzz")
                        .extend(new Notification.WearableExtender().addAction(action))
                        .build();
```

I want an action specific to the Wearable, so I have no choice but to use `Notification.WearableExtender()`.  But it's addAction method only accepts an action as it's parameter. Here is my code for creating an action:

```
            Notification.Action action =
                Notification.Action.Builder(R.drawable.buzz_icon, actionIntent.toString(), pendingIntent);
```

Which doesn't work, as Android Studio says "Method call expected"
How can I successfully create a `Notification.Action`?
Or how else might I add a Wearable specific action to my notification?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're on the right track.

You need to *create* a new `NotificationCompat.Action.Builder` and *then* call `build()` on it. Like this:

```
NotificationCompat.Action action = 
    new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_call, "Only in wearable", pendingIntent)
        .build();
```

Also, make sure that the action is defined as `NotificationCompat.Action`, not `Notification.Action`.

Answer (score 2):

This example illustrates how to add a notification with an action (e.g. open the main activity).

```
 NotificationCompat.Builde mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, null);
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
 PendingIntent myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, myIntent, 0);

 mBuilder.setContentTitle("Your_title")
                .setContentText("Some_text")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
                .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .addAction(R.drawable.open_icon, "Open", myPendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(false);

NotificationManager mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotifyManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```